# Is there any HUD cue that indicates that you can Unite Morph?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

I'm on Operation-007A which starts you out with a very limited number of wonderfuls and not many ways to get more.  So in each combat phase, I try to attack something only to have my character start wailing away with their default attack without a way to cancel until they get smashed in the face.  Is there any sort of way to tell that you can do a unite morph, whether it be a weapon unite or even unite guts, on the HUD or just in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here, as noted in Toomai's answer, is to recruit enemy foot-soldiers to your team as early as possible to increase your numbers. In Mission 001, when the two mid-size enemies show up, one of the first things they'll do is call in a squad of little enemies to support them. What you need to do is hit these guys just hard enough to put them near-death (they'll stop moving and start to glow a light-purplish light) and then wrap them in a Wonder-Circle. This will have the same effect as if you were recruiting a civilian: the enemy will be converted to an ally and join your team, increasing your combat potential and giving you a better chance at survival.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I didn't really understand how to recruit enemies.  I knew that you could do it in the flashback mission and also in the final missions, but it usually happened automatically, so I figured you could **only** do it then.  Wonder-lining them while they are at low health makes a lot more sense.  Do they have to be at red level or can they be at yellow?

Comment: They have to be actually dead, just not exploded yet. Hitting them in this state will make them blow up faster as well, so using Spike Guts as your main damage method is the safest way to get them (block attack, let spikes deal damage, recruit those that died, repeat on those that didn't).

Comment: Yes, Toomai is correct; I used the term "near-death" to describe what happens when they're out of health but not destroyed yet. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem, and yeah there doesn't seem to be any way you can tell whether you have 10 people available to morph with. All you can really do is migitate the problem by recruiting as many enemies as you can in Mission 001.